# A sum of irrational numbers is an algebraic integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am asked to show that $$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5} - \sqrt{17} \Big(\frac{7 - \sqrt{13}}{2} \Big)$$ is an algebraic integer.

$\textbf{Definition:}$  An algebraic integer is the root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

So we start by letting $$x = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{5} - \sqrt{17} \Big(\frac{7 - \sqrt{13}}{2} \Big)$$ and then raise both sides to some power.  I tried squaring both sides, but that didn't seem to help, nor did I think it would get rid of the cube root of five.  My next guess is to raise both sides to the $6th$ power.  Before I try this by hand, I entered it into Wolfram alpha, and found that the minimal polynomial was a $24$th degree polynomial.

Is this method I am trying correct?  What is the trick that I am missing?  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you need to find a suitable polynomial 'by hand' then you can peel off: $x-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{17}(\frac12(7-\sqrt{13}))=\sqrt[3]{5}$, so you can cube both sides of this, etc. This gets painful in a hurry, though.  Instead, you might consider what operations algebraic integers are closed under...

Comment: Have you learned yet the theorem that the sum, difference, or product of algebraic integers is again an algebraic integer?

Comment: @BarrySmith Yes I have.  I believe I have more reading to do though before I try to continue on this problem.

Comment: @AlexWertheim  We have not yet discussed nor do I believe we will cover finite extensions.

Comment: It is possible, though hardly instructive, to find a monic polynomial over $\Bbb Z$ with your number as a root. Better by far to use the approach of @Ennar and Robert Israel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that algebraic integers form a ring, so since $\sqrt 2$, $\sqrt[3]5$ and $\sqrt{17}$ are obviously algebraic integers, it is enough to show that $\alpha=\frac{7-\sqrt{13}}2$ is an algebraic integer.

Since we have $7-2\alpha = \sqrt{13}$, by squaring it follows that $4\alpha^2-28\alpha + 36 = 0$. Dividing by $4$ we get that $\alpha$ is a root of monic $x^2 - 7x + 9$, thus an algebraic integer. The claim follows.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  A clear and concise explanation in which even my simple mind can comprehend!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad that the input is helpful.

Comment: Is this the same concept of integral dependence that Atiyah MacDonald discusses in Chapter 5?

Comment: @mathamphetamines, currently I don't have a copy at my disposal, but the key is that $\alpha$ is algebraic integer if and only if $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ is finitely generated abelian group. Using this, it's easy to show that algebraic integers do form a ring (i.e. are closed under sum and multiplication) and this is all that is needed for this answer to be formally correct.

Comment: @mathamphetamines This is a special case of integral dependence.  Within the complex numbers, a number is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e.,  satisfies an equation of integral dependence over $\mathbb{Z}$) if and only if it is an algebraic integer.

Answer (score 3):

$(7-\sqrt{13})/2$ is a root of the quadratic $x^2 - 7 x + 9$, so it is an algebraic integer.  Of course $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt[3]{5}$, $\sqrt{17}$ are algebraic integers.  The rest is taken care of by the fact that the algebraic integers form a ring.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you very much.  That makes more sense, especially since I don't have a clue about finite extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Observe that you have $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{13}$, $\sqrt{17}$, and $\sqrt[3]{5}$ in the expression.  Each of these (individually) gives an extension of degree $2$, $2$, $2$, and $3$, respectively.  The product of these is $24$.

Therefore, we only need to look at: $1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^{24}$.  If we treat each $x^i$ as a linear combination of products of $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{13}$, $\sqrt{17}$, and $\sqrt[3]{5}$, we can use linear algebra to find the appropriate coefficients to have a nontrivial solution (polynomial).

This is *not* the most efficient solution, but it will work.  A more computational solution would use resultants (but that's more algebraic geometry).

Comment: So finite extensions is the most efficient way to tackle this problem?  The linear algebra "trick" you mentioned was shown to us last lecture.  Thank you for the hint.